# docker: different PID for `top` and `ps`

Tags: linux, docker

I don't understand the difference in

```
$> docker top lamp-test
PID                 USER                COMMAND
31263               root                {supervisord} /usr/bin/python   /usr/bin/supervisord -n
31696               root                {mysqld_safe} /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
31697               root                apache2 -D FOREGROUND
...
```

and

```
$> docker exec lamp-test ps
PID TTY          TIME CMD
  1 ?        00:00:00 supervisord
433 ?        00:00:00 mysqld_safe
434 ?        00:00:00 apache2
831 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

So, the question is, why are the PID different ? I would say that the output from `ps` is namespaced, but if that is true, what is `top` showing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`docker exec lamp-test ps` show `pids` inside docker container.

`docker top lamp-test` show host system `pids`.

You can see a container processes, but You cannot kill them. This "flawed" isolation actually has some great benefits, like the ability to monitor the processes running inside all your containers from a single [monitor](http://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/runmetrics/) process running on the host machine.

Comment: So which means that processes inside a container also have a PID on the host, why ? I thought that these processes run in some kind of virtual environment and cannot be seen from outside. Now I can kill these processes from outside right ?

Comment: Docker is not a VM. It's some kind of `chroot` (LXC). Host can see container processes, but container processes cannot see host proceses. Basic isolation.

Comment: When I try to kill such process `kill 31696` I get `kill: 31696: No such process` So why do I have to do `docker exec lamp-test kill 433` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should worry about this. You can't kill the PID in Host environment, but can do it in container.

1. `docker exec <CONTAINER NAME> ps` remember the PID
2. `docker exec <CONTAINER NAME> kill <PID>`